# Are there any modules I'm missing to help me write better code?

Tags: perl, code-analysis

I'm using the following command to test my perl code:

perl -MB::Lint::StrictOO -MO=Lint,all,oo -M-circular::require -M-indirect -Mwarnings::method -Mwarnings::unused -c $file

On a system with a perl version less than 5.10 I am also using uninit.

I am also using Perl::Critic and Perl::Tidy and have set up the appropriate rc files to my liking.

These modules have done a great job in helping me break some bad habits I learned when first learning perl.

Are there any more modules or pragmas that will kick me back on the straight and narrow when I mess up?

Using tests, and the Test::* family of modules and some good books have been pointed out. This new information has caused me to reconsider some assumptions about the relationship between testing and code skill building.  These are all appreciated and already being researched and put to use.

It seems to me that these are two separate parts of a whole.  'perl -c', Perl::Critic and Perl::Tidy all help during the process of writing code and before execution of code. Devel::Cover, Devel::NYTProf and Tests happen during and after execution of code.

Good development dictates an iterative process, so tests will be run, and code developed over and over, but we still have this separation.

It appears to me that the focus in the answers have been on the 'during and after execution' of code.  Again, this is very appreciated. Can I assume that I have the 'writing and pre-execution' part down pretty well then? At least, insomuch as the pragmas, modules and utilities are concerned.

Comment: Might be time to learn your way around Test::More if you haven't already done so.  Training yourself to write tests ahead of their target code will encourage you to code in smaller, more manageable, and often more general chunks.  And testing your code has to lead to better code, if one definition of better is less buggy.  Many of the Test::* modules provide additional checks without much effort.

Comment: I use the Test:: series of modules a lot ... I hadn't considered tests as a way of improving my coding skills. I use DistZilla whenever possible and that makes using tests very easy, which I take advantage of. Looks like I need to go back and start evaluating the Test:: modules in a new light.

Comment: There are also some really good books out there.  Higher Order Perl.  Modern Perl.  (Both available free online, legitimately.)  There are many others, but those two are good books for learning an enlightened approach to Perl.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little worried that you're using Perl 5.9. For two reasons.

Firstly it's a little old. 5.9.0 was released in 2003 and 5.9.5 (the last version in the 5.9.x series) was released in 2007. There have been several high quality versions of Perl since then.

Secondly (and most importantly), 5.9 is an unstable development version of Perl. 5.9 is basically the series of experiments that eventually led to Perl 5.10.0. The only reason to use it is to test that 5.10 will be a stable version of Perl. No-one should be using it at all now.

Comment: :] I agree, no one *should* be using anything less than 5.10 ... probably even 5.14 ... however what should be and what is are usually two different things.  I work on legacy code a lot.  Some of the servers I work on are still using 5.004.

Comment: Right. I can (just) understand why you might be using a painfully ancient version of Perl. But I can't understand why you'd be using an unstable development version.

Comment: My apologies ... I'm not using 5.9 anywhere that I'm aware of ... when I researched why uninit was failing on a box with 5.14 I found that uninit was removed in 5.10.  The code that generates the command checks for '$] < 5.010' so I tend to think 'anything 5.9 and below'. Sorry for the confusion on that.

Comment: Or you could just type `perl -v` on the command line to find out which version you have :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to be testing your code, merely checking that it will compile.  I suggest that you look at Test::More (which makes writing actual tests nice and easy), Test::Class (which makes dealing with very large test suites easier), and Devel::Cover (to see which bits of your code are covered by your tests and which aren't).

Comment: I am testing my code whenever possible. I just hadn't considered it to be part of improving my coding skills. I'll be looking at the Test:: family of modules in a different light now.

Comment: I'd say that if it's ever impossible to test your code (which is implied by you testing whenever possible) then you should re-write it to *make* it possible! I realise that this isn't always practical - eg if you're talking to some external services - but it's something you should always aim to do. If you do have to deal with an untestable external interface, then consider separating the code to talks to it from the rest of your application, so that you can mock that interface and at least test as much as possible.

And you really should look at Devel::Cover.  It has saved my job in the past.